# Remove specific words and symbol from a df

Tags: r, cpu-word

I have a dataframe structure like this, 39 rows

```
        text.
  "A" OR "B" OR "C"
  "C" OR "D" OR "E"
```

and a "black list" of words that I want to delete, that begin and end with the symbol **"**. (200 words) here an example:

```
   blackList
      "A"
      "D"
```

i want to remove them from the starting dataframe, obtaining:

```
        text.
    OR "B" OR "C"
    "C" OR OR "E"
```

how can I do? I tried with removeWords, but it does not read the symbol **"**.

Comment: can you provide `dput(myData)` in your question instead of pasting the data values?

Answer (score 1):

We could create a pattern by pasting all the blacklisted items together with "|" as collapsable argument and then remove all of them.

```
df$text <- gsub(paste0(blacklist$blackList, collapse = "|"), "", df$text)

df
#            text
#1  OR "B" OR "C"
#2 "C" OR  OR "E"
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(text = c('"A" OR "B" OR "C"','"C" OR "D" OR "E"'))
blacklist <- data.frame(blackList = c('"A"', '"D"'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`gsub('\"A\"', "", '"A" OR "B" OR "C"')`

escape the quotes with a backslash and use gsub

Comment: It works, but I have to do it for all the terms of the black list.